# NPM Corrupt or Broken on Linux Machine

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, expo

Unable to install / update anything using NPM since trying to install Expo or Expo CLI.  Not actually sure of the cause.
I'm running Zorin OS (Linux flavour comparable to Ubuntu).

Example command and resulting error:

```
npm i -g npm
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1085
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
Require stack:
- /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js
- /usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1082:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:928:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:121:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:2:14)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1267:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1321:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1125:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:965:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:19) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: [
'/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js',
'/usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
]
}

Node.js v20.0.0``
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling both Node and NPM several times and I always get this error again.  I'm totally stuck.  Please help!

Comment: Consider these tips here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1152570/npm-cant-find-module-semver-error-in-ubuntu-19-04

Comment: That seems to have worked.  Thank you so much for your help!